# How best for an API running on a web server to check its public availability / status

Tags: python, mysql, rest, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have an AWS server that handles end-user registration/  It runs an EC2 linux instance that serves our API via Apache & Python, and which is connected to its data on a separate Amazon RDS instance running mysql.

To remotely admin the system, I set states in a mysql table to control the availability of the registration API to the public user, and also the level of logging for our Python API, which may reference up to 5 concurrent admin preferences (i.e. not a single "log level")

Because our API provides almost two dozen different functions, we need to check the state of the system's availability before any individual function is accessed.  That means there's an SQL Select statement from that table (which only has one record), but for every session of user transaction,s which might involve a half-dozen API calls.  We need to check to see if the availability status has changed, so the user doesn't start an API call and have the database become unavailable in the middle of the process.  Same for the logging preferences.

The API calls return the server's availability, and estimated downtime, back to the calling program (NOT a web browser interface) which handles that situation gracefully.

Is this a commonly accepted approch for handling this?  Should I care if I'm over-polling the status table?  And should I set up mysql with my status table in such a way to make my constant checking more efficient (e.g. cached?) when Python obtains its data?

I should note that we might have thousands of simultaneous users making API requests, not tens of thousands, or millions.

Comment: SO is not the right place to discuss distributed system architecture, SO is about programming. Also it is not a codecwriting service, so we expect the asking user to provide the code he already has written to solve the problem.

Comment: Klaus, my bad -- I thought because this had to do with mysql, and I did the programming, and mysql is a topic here, that asking about the efficiency of using the approach I described fit in with other SO questions.  In the above example, it's a single Select statement, so there's not anything to provide that anyone well-verse in mysql syntax couldn't imagine.  I'll rethink, rewrite or withdraw the question, but even the "Related" questions SO is proposing (with hundreds or thousands of votes) are of the same ilk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy seems off-track, here.

Polling a status table should not be a major hot spot.  A small table, with proper indexes, queried outside a transaction, is a lightweight operation.  With an appropriately-provisioned server, such a query should be done entirely in memory, requiring no disk access.

But that doesn't mean it's a fully viable strategy.

> We need to check to see if the availability status has changed, so the user doesn't start an API call and have the database become unavailable in the middle of the process.

This will prove impossible.  You need time travel capability for this strategy to succeed.

Consider this: the database becoming unavailable in the middle of a process wouldn't be detected by your approach.  Only the lack of availability at the beginning would be detected.  And that's easy enough to detect, anyway -- you will realize that as soon as you try to do something.

Set appropriate timeouts. The MySQL client library should have support for a connect timeout, as well as a timeout which will cause your application to see an error if a query runs longer than is acceptable or a network disruption causes the connection to be lost mid-query.  I don't know whether this exists or what it's called in Python but in the C client library, this is [`MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-options.html) and is *very* handy for preventing a hang when for whatever reason you get no response from the database within an acceptable period of time.

Use database transactions, so that a failure to process a request results in no net change to the database.  A MySQL transaction is implicitly rolled back if the connection between the application and the database is lost.

Implementing error handling and recovery -- written into your code -- is likely the more viable approach than trying to prevent your code from running when the service is unavailable is more likely to be a good design, because there is no check interval small enough to fully avoid a database becoming unavailable "in the middle" of a request.

In any event, polling a database table with each request seems like the wrong approach, not to mention the fact that an outage on the health status table's server makes your service fail unnecessarily when the service itself might have been healthy but failed to prove that.

On the other hand, I don't know your architecture, but assuming your front-end involves something like Amazon Application Load Balancer or HAProxy, the health checks against the API service endpoint can actually perform the test.  If you configure your check interval for, say, 10 seconds, and making a request to the check endpoint (say GET /health-check) actually verifies end-to-end availability of the necessary components (e.g. database access) then the API service can effectively take itself offline when a problem occurs.  It remains offline until it starts returning success again.

The advantage here is that your workload involved in healthy checking is consistent -- it happens every 10 seconds, increasing with the number of nodes providing the service, but not increasing with actual request traffic, because you don't have to perform a check for each request.  This means you have a window of a few seconds between the actual loss of availability and the detection of the loss of availability, but the requests that get through in the mean time will fail, anyway.

HAProxy -- and presumably other tools like Varnish or Nginx -- can help you handle graceful failures in other ways as well, by timing out failed requests at a layer before the API endpoint so that the caller gets a response even though the service itself didn't respond.  An example from one of my environments is a shopping page where an external API call is made by the application when a site visitor is browsing items by category.  If this request runs longer than it should, the proxy can interrupt the request and return a preconfigured static error page to the system making the request with an error -- say, in JSON or XML, that the requesting application will understand -- so that the hard failure becomes a softer one.  This fake response can, for example in this case, return an empty JSON array of "items found."

It isn't entirely clear to me, now, whether these APIs are yours, or are external APIs that you are aggregating.  If the latter, then HAProxy is a good solution here, too, but facing the other direction -- the back-end faces outward and your service contacts its front-end.  You access the external service through the proxy and the proxy checks the remote service and will immediately return an error back to your application if the target API is unhealthy.  I use this solution to access an external trouble ticketing system from one of my apps.  An additional advantage, here, is that the proxy logs allow me to collect usage, performance, and reliability data about all of the many requests passed to that external service regardless of which of dozens of internal systems may access it, with far better visibility than I could accomplish than if I tried to collect it from all of the internal application servers that access that external service.

Comment: Michael, this is extraordinary detail, and exactly the kind of answer I was interested in.  Let me clarify that I was assuming that an admin "downing" the server would require at least a 5 minute wait time before actually doing anything to make sure no users were in the middle of transactions.  The system is already OK if the user is in the middle of multiple API calls -- it's only within the API call that trouble can occur.  And the status table we are polling is on the same mysql server that all the other transaction data goes, so if one is out, the entire system is down. ALSO: my API.